# on form submit update database with while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the value of "completed" in my database, it is a checkbox so I want to update the value to a 1 or 0 depending on the change in the database, I know this is not the cleanest way of doing it, but once I have got it working I will clean that up!

Ryan

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$task_name = $_POST['task_name'];
$completed = $_POST['completed'];

mysql_query("UPDATE `tasks` SET `completed` = '$completed' WHERE `task_name` = $task_name");

}


$deets = $_POST['deets'];
$deets = preg_replace('#[^0-9/]#i', '', $deets);

$tasks = '';
$query = mysql_query('SELECT task_name, task_description, completed FROM tasks WHERE "'.$deets.'" BETWEEN `start_date` AND  `end_date` ');
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num_rows > 0) {
    $tasks .= '<div id="tasksControl"><button onMouseDown="overlay()">Close</button> <b> ' . $deets . '</b> <br /><br /></div>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $task_name = $row['task_name'] ;
        $task_description = $row['task_description'];
        $task_completed = $row['completed'];
        $tasks .= '<div id="tasksBody">
                    <form method="post">Completed? <input name="completed" type="checkbox" '.
                    ($task_completed == 1?'checked="checked"':'').
                    ' /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"><br /><br />
                    <b>'.$task_name.'</b><br /><br />'.$task_description.'<hr><br />
                    <input type="hidden" value="$task_name" name="TaskName" /></form></div>';
        }
}
echo $tasks;
?>
```

Comment: So what is really your problem? The database is not updating? Checkboxes not being checked? please specify your problem and what you want to happen.

Comment: The database is not actually updating

Comment: did you try using var_dump($_POST['completed']); before the update query? what is the value of the $_POST['completed'] when checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: unchecked is 0, and checked is 1. I hadn't tried that, but i just did and didn't work

Comment: In your database, what is the field type of `completed` field?

Comment: int(1) is the field type

Comment: Just FYI, it is displaying correctly in the checkbox, for example if the task is marked as 1 in the db, the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please try it out. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the completed column uses 0 for unchecked and 1 for checked, you need to change this line:

```
$completed = $_POST['completed'];
```

If the checkbox is unchecked, $_POST['completed'] will be null/empty, as the web browser will not submit it.

```
$completed = intval($_POST['completed']);
```

using `intval()` will force a 1 or a 0.

Edit:

You should also escape `$task_name`:

```
$task_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['task_name']);
```

And us quotes in the SQL:

```
 "UPDATE tasks SET completed = '$completed' WHERE task_name = '$task_name'"
```

Comment: Hi Paul, it is still not working, I have tested the query itself on the database and it is working.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `completed` = '$completed' WHERE `task_name` = $task_name";
var_dump($sql);
mysql_query($sql);
var_dump(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

try changing your update query to:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `tasks` SET `completed` = $completed WHERE `task_name` = $task_name")or die(mysql_error());
```

remove the single quote (`'`) to the `$completed` variable.

Comment: I have updated my answer to check if your query got a mysql error.

Comment: Hi, no there is no issue with the query

Comment: maybe you are updating another table or database. please check it carefully.